# Could not find file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0'

Tags: c#, asp.net, syncfusion

i define a master page with some menu items. Im  using the file upload control, I just have an issue with displaying the contents of a file to open it on another content Page: newModel.aspx page. its working will but i cant display the content, im getting an Error:
Could not find file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0\C%3a%5cUsers%5chhassan%5cDocuments%5cVisual+Studio+2010%5cWebSites%5cKBD-2013%5cModel%5cTest.edd'.

C# MasterPage-code:

```
protected void Open_btn_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool fileOK = false;
    string SampleDocuments = Server.MapPath(string.Empty);
    if (FileUploadCtrl.HasFile)
    {
        string fileExtension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUploadCtrl.FileName).ToLower();
        string allowedExtension = ".edd";
        if (fileExtension == allowedExtension)
        {
            fileOK = true;
        }
    }
    if (fileOK == true)
    {

        string fileName = SampleDocuments + "\\Model" + "\\" + FileUploadCtrl.FileName;
        Response.Redirect("~/Model/newModel.aspx?fileName=" + fileName);
    }
```

newModel Page Code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String fileName = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Request.QueryString["fileName"]);
    this.DiagramWebControl1.LoadBinaryDocument(fileName);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your application runs in a hosted mode (IIS, IIS Development server), you have to work with `Server.MapPath("~")` to get the actual directory. By default, the current working directory points to the working directory of your web server. 
For more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath.aspx

Comment: my application is running on a localhost

Comment: But you use IIS? Or IIS Development Server?

Comment: sorry i forget to write it im using IIS

Comment: Ok, it does not matter if you are on localhost or on your production machine. If you use IIS, then you have to use `Server.MapPath`.